# check if non unique table value, always corrosponds with other value

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
+----------+-------------+----------+------+----------+
| suite_id | building_id | bedrooms | rent | occupied |
+----------+-------------+----------+------+----------+
|      745 |        1000 |        1 |  800 |        0 |
|      746 |        1000 |        1 |  810 |        1 |
|      747 |        1000 |        2 | 1000 |        0 |
|      748 |        1002 |        2 | 1010 |        0 |
|      749 |        1004 |        2 | 1020 |        1 |
|      750 |        1010 |        1 |  750 |        0 |
|      751 |        1020 |        2 |  950 |        0 |
|      752 |        1020 |        1 |  400 |        1 |
|      753 |        1020 |        2 | 1200 |        0 |
|      754 |        1020 |        5 | 3000 |        0 |
|      755 |        1030 |        2 | 1100 |        0 |
|      760 |        1006 |        1 |  500 |        1 |
|      761 |        1006 |        2 |  900 |        1 |
|      762 |        1006 |        2 |  950 |        1 |
|      770 |        1180 |        2 |  990 |        1 |
|      771 |        1180 |        1 |  600 |        1 |
|      772 |        1180 |        2 |  900 |        0 |
|      773 |        1170 |        3 | 1100 |        1 |
|      774 |        1170 |        2 | 1000 |        1 |
|      780 |        1160 |        1 |  200 |        1 |
|      781 |        1160 |        2 |  400 |        1 |
|      782 |        1004 |        2 | 1100 |        1 |
|      783 |        1004 |        2 | 1111 |        1 |
+----------+-------------+----------+------+----------+
```

now what I need to do is check if any buildings aren't occupied, which would be just 1030 (I think). I believe I need to check each building id, see if it's ever occupied(set to 1), and if it isn't then have that returned. this is an assignment, and we've just began working with mysql, so try to keep it relatively simple, thanks.

Comment: `...GROUP BY building_id HAVING SUM(occupied) = 0`

Comment: thanks a lot! that was actually really straight forward haha

Comment: @WyattGrant.  Yes, researching HAVING, it is what you use quite a bit for constraints in group operations.